# How to change time display to 12h time format in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome-shell, clock

I have installed **Ubuntu 18.04** and I have the following issue:

I tried to change the date on the top panel to **12h format** instead of the default **24h format** but I found no editable option into settings or `gnome-tweaks` tool.

I hope to find help here.

Comment: Settings > Date & Time > 24 hrs or am/pm. cli: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format '12h'` -should be a dupe of something.

Comment: It works via cli and there's no data & time option in 18.04, add it in an answer so anyone can find help throw the question.

Comment: To my surprise, I found no literal dupe with a working answer quickly. I'll leave the GUI option, since it is present on my Ubuntu Budgie 18.04

Comment: Yes, you're right. I found that I had something wrong with that installation and I had many things missed (including this issue), so I reinstalled my ubuntu and everything works fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. From GUI (Settings):

   Open **Settings >Details> Date & Time**. Then pick either 24 hrs or am/pm
2. From GUI (using dconf-editor)

   Open **dconf Editor** (not installed by default, run

   ```
   sudo apt install dconf-editor
   ```

   to install), and browse to <kbd>org</kbd> > <kbd>gnome</kbd> > <kbd>desktop</kbd> > <kbd>interface</kbd> > <kbd>clock-format</kbd>, and change the format to `'12h'`

   [image]
3. From command line:

   Run the command:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format '12h'
   ```

   To revert:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format '24h'
   ```

Comment: I found another solution using `dconf` can I edit your answer and add it?

Comment: @AboElnouR OK, can't find it quickly, but `gsettings` is the cli frontend to `dconf`. `gsettings` is usually slightly slower, higher level, but includes a consistency check to the `dconf` database.

Comment: I just wanted to provide another solution to those who may not understand this command, But it's Ok.

Comment: @AboElnouR Ah, wait, you mean using dconf editor (GUI)?

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @AboElnouR right! added.

Answer (score 2):

To run the following commands, first install the `dconf-editor` package:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then run this command, to switch to 12-hour mode:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format '12h'
```

If you ever want to revert to 24-hour mode, you can do so by running:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format '24h'
```

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the date and time located in the panel.

Change the capital R to lower-case r.