# Cannot change clock to 24 hour format in Ubuntu Gnome

Tags: gnome

[image: GUI]I've read the three solutions on [How to change time display to 12h time format in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038952/how-to-change-time-display-to-12h-time-format-in-ubuntu) and set my time to 24 hour in the GUI and using gnome-tweak and I've managed to change my time and date format nicely, but cannot set 24 hour clock: the "AM" is still showing.  This is in spite of

1. "Time Format" being set to "24-hour" within the GUI, (see figure above)
2. Entering in the command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format '24h'`
3. and setting within browse to org > gnome > desktop > interface > clock-format within `dconf-editor`, and change the format to '24h'

How can I get the 24 hour clock format, is there some other setting that could be contradicting these three methods?

Comment: how did you set the time to 24 hour via GUI? can you attach a pic which is showing 24hr format with AM?

Comment: @PRATAP I've added a screenshot of the GUI.  I followed Open Settings >Details> Date & Time.

Comment: yes.. thats clear.. can you post the output of this command? `gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions`

Comment: @PRATAP `con@VB:~/Pictures$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions` gives `@as []`

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format` whats the output of this command?

Comment: Are you using some Gnome Extension to show the time on the right? It might be ignoring the Gnome setting.

Comment: @PRATAP `con@VB:~/Pictures$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format` gives `'24h'`

Comment: @con your OS is Ubuntu or Kubuntu?

Comment: @PRATAP my OS is Ubuntu

Comment: version? and what are the outputs of these two commands? `env | grep SESSION_DESKTOP` and `env | grep CURRENT_DESKTOP`
`

Comment: @PRATAP `env | grep SESSION_DESKTOP` gives `XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome-flashback-metacity`

Comment: @PRATAP `env | grep CURRENT_DESKTOP` gives `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME-Flashback:GNOME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are using GNOME-Flashback

run the below command

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 24-hour`

for 12-hour

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 12-hour`

or to reset to default value

`gsettings reset com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format`

Alternatively you can use dconf-editor tool (`sudo apt install dconf-editor`)

[image]